# Socket read IOException not being caught?

Tags: java, json, grails, grails-2.2

In grails, can the socket read failed or ioexception be caught? The following error is triggered even though i have wrapped the error part in try catch block.

```
ERROR 2021-03-28 08:34:10,170 [ajp-bio-8109-exec-39783] errors.GrailsExceptionResolver: IOException occurred when processing request: [POST] /race/results/
Socket read failed. Stacktrace follows:
java.io.IOException: Socket read failed
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(PushbackInputStream.java:186)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:140)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1485)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1461)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1436)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:585)
    at grails.converters.JSON.parse(JSON.java:312)
    at grails.converters.JSON.parse(JSON.java:347)
```

At the point where the error is thrown i have wrapped it within try catch block as shown below.

```
 def results(){


        def results


        try {

            results = request.JSON


        } catch (IOException e1) {

            log.error "ERROR WHILE request.json in /results******************************************************************"

            render contentType: "text/json", text: '{"status":"fail"}'
            return

        }
```

The error is thrown at this point

```
results = request.JSON
```

I appreciate any insights. I am using Grails 2.2.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Here is the full stacktrace. Thanks!

```
ERROR 2021-03-28 08:34:10,170 [ajp-bio-8109-exec-39783] errors.GrailsExceptionResolver: IOException occurred when processing request: [POST] /race/results/
Socket read failed. Stacktrace follows:
java.io.IOException: Socket read failed
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(PushbackInputStream.java:186)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:140)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1485)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1461)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1436)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:585)
    at grails.converters.JSON.parse(JSON.java:312)
    at grails.converters.JSON.parse(JSON.java:347)
    at race.results(VirtualRaceController.groovy:2011)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Look at the stack trace; it appears the exception is being thrown later in the process.

Comment: Actually, that looks like a *partial* stacktrace.  Something is calling `grails.converters.JSON.parse` ... and it doesn't look like it is the code in the question.

Comment: this is calling json.parse             results = request.JSON

Comment: Please add the complete stack trace.

Comment: i have added the full stacktrace. thanks!

Comment: i wish someone uped the question to remove negative marks : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably find it is throwing ConverterException, not IOException. Here is the code:

```
class ConvertersExtension {
    static getJSON(HttpServletRequest request) {
        JSON.parse(request)
    }
}
public class JSON  {
   public static Object parse(HttpServletRequest request) throws ConverterException {
       // blah blah
       try {
            /// blah blah
       }
       catch (IOException e) {
           throw new ConverterException("Error parsing JSON", e);
       }
   }  
}
```

If you're using an IDE, right click on the API in question and select "GO To declaration", or whatever the equivilent is in your IDE until you trace your way up to see what throws what.

Comment: thank you. the exception has been caught. i changed the type from IOException to ConverterException in try catch block.